# pcl_visualization-eigen-package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found pcl_visualization in the following:

- svn:
  uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/perception_pcl_addons/tags/unstable

When I am trying to run rosmake perception_pcl_addons i get the follwoing error:

'pcl_visualization' depends on non-existent package 'eigen'

I have eigen-config.cmake  eigen-config-version.cmake in:

/opt/ros/groovy/share/eigen/cmake$

Can I generate the eigen package from this eigen-config.cmake?

Or where can I find that package?

I am have groovy installed in my system

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63925/pcl_visualization-eigen-package/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That looks like pretty old code. Anything actively developed is probably somewhere on github now.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0